# solr joins with multi-tenant data

Tags: search, solr, sharding, solrcloud

I use solr to store data of multiple applications, currently routing one application data to one shard using compositeId routing with app name as the shard key
Ex: myapp!docid

however I observed recently one of the app data seems to be growing significantly and is expected to quadruple in coming months, so I wanted to try multi-tenant approach of using different shard key

Ex: myapp/2!docid

so that data is routed to 1/4 of shards instead of single shard.

1. There are lot of joins and ngroups in our app, what would be the impact of this, since changing the shard key for the app would spread docs across multiple shards, do these still work  ?
2. All our apps are using same collection, does using a different shard key for one of the app requires re-indexing other apps data ?
   Ex: all existing apps using **app name** as shard key and now for one of the app we planning to change it to **app name/2** to leverage multiple shards for that app

Also what's the difference between solr shard and solr core, on some of the blogs I read, for joins and ngroups to work the documents need to be colocated on same core or vm. so I am assuming core here means shard.

Comment: A core is the term that describes a self-contained Solr store on a single node (back when there was no such as thing as cloud/cluster mode, that was really all you had). A shard describes a core that's used as part of a larger collection - i.e. behind the scenes it's still a core, but when talking about a shard it's part of a larger collection. A core might not be a shard (if it just lives by itself), but a shard will always be a core. [1..n] shards make up a collection (in the "old" days you'd do sharding manually with the `shards` parameter, now you usually use the collection abstraction).

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks, Do solr joins work across shards in solr cloud ?, since shard is always a core in solr cloud, will the joins provide wrong results if docs of a single app are spread across multiple shards

Comment: It kind of .. depends. See the notes and example on https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/other-parsers.html#joining-across-single-shard-collections - the collection you're using in `fromIndex` needs to be present on all nodes and with a single shard. But you can also use the more recent crossjoin query parser: https://solr.apache.org/guide/8_6/other-parsers.html#cross-collection-join which works with the streaming expressions support in the background (streaming expressions would work for joins in this case, regardless of other limitations)